# SQLite Query is not returning results

Tags: android, sqlite

I created an SQLite Database for an Android application and it has been working fine so far but a specific query is returning no results.
I'm completely new to SQL so if there is something trivial wrong with my query I would like to know.

```
SELECT word,freq FROM wordlist WHERE word = '%ras' AND dist = 2 ORDER BY freq DESC
```

word is varchar(4) while freq and dist are integers

the table itself has around 4000 or so four letter words and there definitely should be at least one word that satisfies the conditions of a word of the form "_ras" and dist = 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with that,

If you require to fetch the word ending with "ras" then you need to write below query:

```
SELECT word,freq FROM wordlist WHERE word like'%ras' AND dist = 2 ORDER BY freq DESC
```

> There are two wildcards used in conjunction with the LIKE operator:
>
> % will return zero, one, or multiple numbers or characters.
>
> And _ represents a single number or character before the word.

For that you can query like below :

```
SELECT word,freq FROM wordlist WHERE word like'_ras' AND dist = 2 ORDER BY freq DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use 'like' insted of  = for word compatison.

you can try:

```
SELECT word,freq FROM wordlist WHERE word like '%ras' AND dist = 2 ORDER BY freq DESC
```

and if you want results with only on letter before ras try

```
SELECT word,freq FROM wordlist WHERE word like '_ras' AND dist = 2 ORDER BY freq DESC
```